# Excel HYPERLINK() function seemingly broken by hash character "#"

Tags: excel, hyperlink, hashtag

```
=HYPERLINK("file:///C:/Users/dholstei/projects/xmtr%20DB/data_sheet-Instructions.htm#TestDataSheet", "help")
```

in Excel resolves to

```
file:///C:/Users/dholstei/projects/xmtr%20DB/data_sheet-Instructions.htm
```

in the web browser

Interestingly, hovering over the link gives a small pop-up that shows the correct, full target. Variations on that, like concatenating the subsection to the path of a root document don't work either, the subsection is stripped.

Comment: It appears not to be an Excel issue, when I put the string into Windows Explorer, it does the same thing, namely strip the hashtag and everything past it out

Answer (score 0):

[The pound sign is a valid character to use in a file name but is not accepted in hyperlinks in Office documents.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/202261/you-cannot-use-a-pound-character-in-a-file-name-for-a-hyperlink-in-an)